# I have several Errors which i think come from a wrong import

Tags: java, import, printing

The following code returns the following errors :

> The import javax.media cannot be resolved

> ColorSpaceJAI cannot be resolved to a variable

> ColorSpaceJAI cannot be resolved to a variable

> TYPE_CMYK cannot be resolved or is not a field

I am not a professional, but in the past " cannot be resolved " usually meant that I was stupid and got the imports wrong.

This is the code:

```
  import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.jai.ColorSpaceJAI;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FileDropTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the main window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Drop Tool");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add a drop target to the window
        frame.setDropTarget(new java.awt.dnd.DropTarget() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                try {
                    // Accept the drop and get the list of files
                    dtde.acceptDrop(java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<File> files = (List<File>) dtde.getTransferable()
                            .getTransferData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                    // Process the first file
                    File file = files.get(0);
                    // Open the image file
                    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
                    // Check if the image already has the iso_coated_v2 color profile
                    ColorModel colorModel = image.getColorModel();
                    if (colorModel.getColorSpace().getType() == ColorSpaceJAI.TYPE_CMYK &&
                            colorModel.getColorSpace().getName(ColorSpaceJAI.NAME_ISO_COATED)
                                    .equals("ISO Coated v2 300%")) {
                        System.out.println("Image already has the iso_coated_v2 color profile");
                    } else {
                        // Convert the image to the iso_coated_v2 color profile
                        BufferedImage cmykImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                                BufferedImage.TYPE_CMYK);
                        Graphics2D g2d = cmykImage.createGraphics();
                        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                        g2d.dispose();
                        // Save the converted image to a new file
                        ImageIO.write(cmykImage, "JPEG", new File(file.getParent(), "iso_coated_v2.jpg"));
                        System.out.println("Image converted to iso_coated_v2 color profile and saved to a new file");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Add a label to the window
        frame.add(new JLabel("Drop a file here"));
    }
}
```

This is what the code should do :

- Creates a main window (JFrame) and sets it to be visible.
- Sets a drop target on the main window, which allows the user to drag and drop a file into the window.
- When a file is dropped, the program accepts the drop and retrieves the list of files. It then processes the first file in the list.
- The program opens the image file and checks if it already has the iso_coated_v2 color profile. If it does, it prints a message to the console. If not, it converts the image to the iso_coated_v2 color profile.

Comment: There is no constant `TYPE_CMYK` in [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html). I do not think that this stems from a "wrong import" since `Bufferedimage` is a standard `awt` class. Where did the `TYPE_CMYK` originally come from, i.e. who wrote that code? I suggest talking to that person.

Comment: A friend of mine said he "made a little programm" but it it returns several error, as i am only a student I looked at the code which i found well documented but the only problem i could think of on point were the imports ,so I asked the question :). Ok update uppon asking he has admitted to have used Chat GPT ,no wonder the code has errors and he doesnt know anything about them.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem `ColorSpaceJAI cannot be resolved to a variable` and `TYPE_CMYK cannot be resolved or is not a field`

you need to import this lib to your project
[jai-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jai-core/1.1.3)

and change

```
BufferedImage cmykImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_CMYK);
```

to

```
BufferedImage cmykImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),ColorSpaceJAI.TYPE_CMYK);
```

And I still can't find `ColorSpaceJAI.NAME_ISO_COATED`,it looks like some other tripartite library

Comment: What hes trying to do ,and what i am now trying to do is a programm where you can drop an image with any color space you want and getting an output image that uses the iso_coated_v2 printable color space . Since I now know ,that the code is made per ai it could be that the library as refered to in the code does not exsist.

Comment: Using your link i get an 404 error. Is it a oracle site or from some inside   java-community

Comment: Oh, I think I lost the version number when I pasted it. I changed it

Comment: Yea Link works now i will try out your suggestions

Comment: Hmm somehow i am not able to import (i get no downloadable jar file so ) but thanks for your help :)

Comment: lol,may be you need to change your project to maven project and you can import it easily.It looks like there's a long way to go